# How to calculate % to total for multiple variables?

Tags: r, dplyr

```
students <- data.frame( names = c( "Bill", "Stacey", "Fred", "Jane", "Sarah" ), 
                        gender = c( "M", "F", "M", "F", "F" ),
                        age = c( "10-12", "10-12", "13-15", "7-9", "16-18" ),
                        stringsAsFactors = FALSE )
```

I have used the function below for one variable however, it doesnt work for multiple variables.

```
library(dplyr)
result_dplyr <- students %>%
group_by(gender) %>%
summarise(per_to_tot = n() / nrow(student) * 100)
print(result_dplyr)
```

Desired output is below.

```
#    gender per to tot
# 1:      M 40
# 2:      F 60
#    age  
# 1:     7-9   20
# 2:     10-12 40
# 3:     13-15 20
# 4:     16-18 20
```

R code that works for multiple variables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try

```
lapply(students[-1], \(x) as.data.frame(proportions(table(x)) * 100))
```

which gives

```
$gender
  x Freq
1 F   60
2 M   40

$age
      x Freq
1 10-12   40
2 13-15   20
3 16-18   20
4   7-9   20
```

Answer (score 4):

```
library(tidyverse)
students |>
  pivot_longer(-names) |>
  count(name, value) |>
  mutate(pct = 100 * n / sum(n), .by = name) |>
  group_split(name)
```

Result

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 4 × 4
  name  value     n   pct
  <chr> <chr> <int> <dbl>
1 age   10-12     2    40
2 age   13-15     1    20
3 age   16-18     1    20
4 age   7-9       1    20

[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  name   value     n   pct
  <chr>  <chr> <int> <dbl>
1 gender F         3    60
2 gender M         2    40
```

Or we could replace the last line with `nest_by(name)` for

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
# Rowwise:  name
  name                 data
  <chr>  <list<tibble[,3]>>
1 age               [4 × 3]
2 gender            [2 × 3]
```

Or as @TarJae suggested we can use base `split` (which seems simplest with magrittr's pipe `%>%`), to get a named list of output:

```
students |>
  pivot_longer(-names) |>
  count(name, value) |>
  mutate(pct = 100 * n / sum(n), .by = name) %>%
  split(.$name)


$age
# A tibble: 4 × 4
  name  value     n   pct
  <chr> <chr> <int> <dbl>
1 age   10-12     2    40
2 age   13-15     1    20
3 age   16-18     1    20
4 age   7-9       1    20

$gender
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  name   value     n   pct
  <chr>  <chr> <int> <dbl>
1 gender F         3    60
2 gender M         2    40
```

Comment: By replacing `group_split` with `split` (now we have to use `%>%`) and adding one more `map` line we could maybe get a more appealing out? `library(tidyverse)
students  %>% 
  pivot_longer(-names)  %>% 
  count(name, value)  %>% 
  mutate(pct = 100 * n / sum(n), .by = name) %>% 
  split(f = as.factor(.$name)) %>% 
  map(.,~(.x %>%select(-c(name, n))))`

Answer (score 2):

Shortest way I found in tidyverse! Not comparable to @ThomasIsCoding solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

students %>%
  summarise(per_to_tot = n() / nrow(students) * 100, .by = gender) %>% 
  mutate(category1 = "gender") %>% 
  bind_rows(students %>%
              summarise(per_to_tot = n() / nrow(students) * 100, .by=age) %>%
  mutate(category1 = "age")) %>% 
  mutate(gender = coalesce(gender, age), .keep="unused") %>% 
  rename(category = gender) %>% 
  split(f = as.factor(.$category1)) %>% 
  map(.,~(.x %>%select(-category1)))
```

```
$age
  category per_to_tot
3    10-12         40
4    13-15         20
5      7-9         20
6    16-18         20

$gender
  category per_to_tot
1        M         40
2        F         60
```

Comment: doing it separately for both gender and age isn't [great practice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), particularly as we don't know how many columns OP actually wants

Comment: That is true @Mark.

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- data.frame( names = c( "Bill", "Stacey", "Fred", "Jane", "Sarah" ), 
                        gender = c( "M", "F", "M", "F", "F" ),
                        age = c( "10-12", "10-12", "13-15", "7-9", "16-18" ),
                        stringsAsFactors = FALSE )
library(tidyverse)

nm <- str_subset(names(df), "names", negate = TRUE)
map(.x = nm,
    .f = ~ df %>% count(!!sym(.x)) %>% mutate(across(n, function(x) proportions(x) * 100)))
```